# Search in Directories with tuples as keys - python

Tags: python

I created tuples as keys in dictionary and trying to run a search with user input.

```
directory = {('a','b'):1, ('c','d'):2, ('e','f'):3}
numsearch = input("enter number to search: ")

if numsearch in directory.values():
    print(directory.values())
```

or

```
print(directory.items())
```

does not throw any error or output a value.

Appreciate any help if you tell me the error in my code

Comment: You can add some prints to check what is happening in each step, maybe it can help you.

Comment: @ZiMtyth It reads/prints numsearch if thats what you mean

Comment: If the user enters a number, then your dictionary should be inverted, with the numbers as keys and the tuples as values. That way you can turn the user's input into an integer and check if it's in the dictionary.

Comment: @magicleon Got me confused, is numsearch int or str at input and at search?

Comment: @X10nD `numsearch` is a `str`.

Comment: Have you entered a number that is there in the values?

Comment: Oh actually I just checked and I got an integer. Maybe depends on Python version?

Comment: @Zevgon, Are you using the old Python2?

Comment: Yes good call, 2.7

Comment: @BhargavRao  I am not sure why you closed the question because the question which you pointed is not the same as the one I asked here.

Comment: @X10nD, it's still the same, use `int(input("enter number to search: "))` and it'll work for you.

Comment: @BhargavRao Can you respond why you closed the question coz its the not the same

Comment: @X10nD Can you respond as to why it is not the same?

Comment: @BhargavRao For beginners like me those two questions look different but for experts like you it would be like identical twins.  I have already explained above

Comment: @BhargavRao Your saying "use int(input("enter number to search: "))" is not the solution to my question. If you cannot provide a solution do not close or try an answer or confuse the person who asks the question

Comment: @X10nD Did you try it out?

Comment: Can't reproduce issue on python 2.7; programs runs fine as written (I input 3 and get back [3,1,2] ... now if you wanted it to return ('e','f'), that's a different question... but you said you didn't get any output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
directory = {('a','b'):1, ('c','d'):2, ('e','f'):3}
numsearch = input("enter number to search: ")

for k,v in directory.items():
    if int(numsearch) == v:
      print(k)
```

Comment: Can it be done without a loop, like a straight forward print()?